# UPDATE (Event) PROBLEM WITH AJAX ACCORDION CONTROL

Tags: ajax, accordion

I Have three records which I want to display in three Accordion Panes

which (every pane) will have a Header  and a content  ( Two label controls, 1 text box and 1 checkbox and 1 link button)

I am able to display data on the accrodion from database but when I am trying to Update the text in textbox by clicking link button the LINKBUTTON doesnot fire and unabel to make the update. How can we create Update event working ??

I am creating the Accordion Panes and Content controls statically and directly assigning the values to the controls from Code behind in Page Load.

Comment: I am not using any Update Panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using the  "ItemCommand" event of the Accordion Panel by using the Command Name property of a Link Button which will update the Text Boxes.

It works for me now but I felt JQUERY will be a better option which has no postback, css issues..